VSCode crashes upon opening
VSCode has started crashing whenever I open it, and I understand from the error messages it is to do with GPU, but other programs seems to work fine. Here is the error from code --verbose:
[0611/085744.761823:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0611/085744.761840:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:44.769Z] [UtilityProcess type: shared-process, pid: 93779]: successfully created
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:44.789Z] [UtilityProcess id: 1, type: fileWatcher, pid: 93780]: successfully created
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:44.821Z] menubarService#updateMenubar 1
[93542:0611/085744.904369:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 Started scanning system extensions", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[93542:0611/085744.904834:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 Started scanning user extensions [object Object]", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[93542:0611/085744.915371:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 Renderer->UtilityProcess#createWorkerChannel: connection established", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:45.022Z] [UtilityProcess id: 1, type: extensionHost, pid: <none>]: creating new...
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:45.041Z] [UtilityProcess id: 1, type: extensionHost, pid: 93801]: successfully created
[93542:0611/085745.069415:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%c INFO color: #33f Started local extension host with pid 93801.", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[93542:0611/085745.073668:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[93542:0611/085745.074301:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1364)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[93542:0611/085745.102593:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cDEBUG background: #eee; color: #888 Error while reading the extension cache file: /home/eda/.config/Code/CachedProfilesData/__default__profile__/extensions.builtin.cache Unable to read file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/CachedProfilesData/__default__profile__/extensions.builtin.cache' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/CachedProfilesData/__default__profile__/extensions.builtin.cache')", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[93542:0611/085745.120205:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cDEBUG background: #eee; color: #888 Error while reading the extension cache file: /home/eda/.config/Code/CachedProfilesData/__default__profile__/extensions.user.cache Unable to read file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/CachedProfilesData/__default__profile__/extensions.user.cache' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/CachedProfilesData/__default__profile__/extensions.user.cache')", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open i965: /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: i965
MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast: /usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load swrast driver
[93542:0611/085745.445205:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1015)] Reinitialized the GPU process after a crash. The reported initialization time was 0 ms
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:45.483Z] menubarService#updateMenubar 1
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:45.509Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:45.538Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 4)
[main 2024-06-11T07:57:45.733Z] menubarService#updateMenubar 1
[93542:0611/085745.744453:INFO:CONSOLE(655)] "%cTRACE color: #888 Error while resolving configuration file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/User/tasks.json': Unable to read file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/User/tasks.json' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-userdata:/home/eda/.config/Code/User/tasks.json')", source: vscode-file://vscode-app/snap/code/160/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (655)
[0611/085745.822524:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0611/085745.822830:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range


Will be very grateful for any tips on going forward, my troubleshooting has not gotten me far! Thank you
Tried upgrading, updating, reinstalling, switching off extensions, switching off GPU acceleration for VSCode. No change to the problem, VSCode will not start.

recently i had the same issue , i used to install vscode using snap package manager , i uninstalled it ,   and installed manually from  https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Just to save folks the trouble of going to the other answer - code --in-process-gpu will work as a temporary workaround, without rolling back, and VSCode is releasing a fix later this week.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and my VScode also kept crashing after the latest update. I decided to roll back Visual Studio Code to its previous version. This is useful for quickly reverting to a stable release if a new update causes issues or compatibility problems.
I use the following command:
sudo snap revert code

